# Lifetime parameters in a trait

Tags: rust

I'm having difficulties understanding lifetime parameters in the following code snippet.

```
struct C {
    data: Vec<u32>,
    cols: usize
}

trait M<'s> {
    fn get(&'s self, r: usize, c: usize) -> u32;
    fn get_mut(&'s mut self, r: usize, c: usize) -> &'s mut u32;
}

impl<'s> M<'s> for C {
    fn get(&'s self, r: usize, c: usize) -> u32 {
    return self.data[self.cols*r+c];
    }
    fn get_mut(&'s mut self, r: usize, c: usize) -> &'s mut u32 {
    return &mut self.data[self.cols*r+c];
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn create() -> C {
    let data = vec![0u32,1u32,2u32,3u32,4u32,5u32];
    return C{data, cols: 3};
    }

    fn select<'s, 'r: 's>(data: &'r mut dyn M<'s>) {
    let mut _val: u32 = 0;
    for r in 0..2 {
        for c in 0..3 {
        _val += *data.get_mut(r,c);
        }
    }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_select() {
    let mut data = create();
    select(&mut data);
    }

}
```

The code snippet does not compile, because it complains that `*data` is borrowed multiple times in the function `fn select<'s, 'r: 's>(data: &'r mut dyn M<'s>) {}` when calling `get_mut` (once in every loop iteration). Even safeguarding the questionable line with curly braces (and thus creating a new context) does not help. My expectation (in both cases) would be, that the mutable borrow of `&mut data` should end right after the execution of that line.

On the other hand, when I remove all lifetime parameters, everything works as expected.

Can anyone explain what's the difference between the two versions (with and without explicit lifetimes)?

I've also tried to find information about additional lifetime parameters for traits, in particular specifying their meaning, but I have found none. So I assume, that they are just a declaration of the used labels inside the trait. But if that is so, then I would assume that leaving out the lifetime parameters completely and applying the eliding rules would lead to the same result.

Comment: I'm curious about the answer too. In the meantime, a _minor_ stylistic hint. When building your `data` vector, you only need to add `u32` once: `vec![0u32, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` because once you specify that one element is of type `u32`, it follows that the other numbers must be `u32` too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to consider. The first is when you use a generic lifetime for a function, that lifetime must be larger than the life of the function call simply by construction. And the second is since the lifetime `self` is tied to the lifetime parameter of the trait, when you call `.get_mut()`, `data` is borrowed for the lifetime of `'s`. Combining those two principles, `data` is borrowed for longer than the function call so you can't call it again (its already mutably borrowed).

> On the other hand, when I remove all lifetime parameters, everything works as expected. Can anyone explain what's the difference between the two versions (with and without explicit lifetimes)?

Without a generic lifetime on `M`, the methods will behave as if defined as so:

```
impl M for C {
    fn get<'a>(&'a self, r: usize, c: usize) -> u32 {
        return self.data[self.cols * r + c];
    }
    fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, r: usize, c: usize) -> &'a mut u32 {
        return &mut self.data[self.cols * r + c];
    }
}
```

Thus there is no lifetime associated with the trait; the lifetimes given and returned from the function are generic only to those method calls. And since the compiler can choose a new lifetime `'a` for each call and it will always pick the shorted lifetime to satisfy its usage, you can then call `data.get_mut()` multiple times without worry. And I'll be honest, having the lifetime on the trait didn't make much sense with the original code; as mentioned, the code works with all lifetime annotations removed: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=306ef22726ab0ee4a60c66ce0ead8972).

Comment: Just that I understand it correctly: `'s` in `trait M<'s> {}` and `'s` in `fn get<'s>(&'s self, ...)` both relate to the lifetme of the object which is implementing M, but in the first case, this label denotes the actual lifetime of that object, because it can't choose a different lifetime for each function call, while in the second case the compiler can choose a lifetime that is no longer than that of `self`, but it can be chosen anew on each function call and thus be shortened to the actual needs. Or is `'s` in `trait M<'s>` denote a different thing? Then: What is the lifetime of a trait?

Comment: Also, I don't understand in which cases it would be beneficial to have a lifetime parameter for the trait instead of the individual function. It seems to be more restrictive without any additional advantage.

Comment: @user3617992 `'s` in the two places mean different things. When it is in `M<'s>`, it depends on what the trait does. But you would typically not do `M<'s>` and `&'s self` since it runs into issues like listed above. Normally `'s` as part of the trait would be used elsewhere; most commonly for method return types that need to exist for a specific lifetime.

Comment: OK, then if they both mean different things, then I still don't understand, what `'s` in `M<'s>` refers to. When exactly does that lifetime start and when does it end? It's critical to know that in order to use it. But.. whatever. Maybe I will one day run in a situation where I have to use it and then, with an example at the hands, I will understand it better. Thank you, anyways, for your answer!

Comment: @user3617992 Think about what a trait `M<T>` means, what does `T` refer to? Its just a generic parameter, the meaning behind it is dependent on how the trait uses it. The lifetime's start and end depend on the context where the trait is used since it would most commonly be dependent on some other pre-existing lifetime. If you need an example and are familiar at all with `serde`, you can look at [how `Deserialize<'de>` works](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html). As I said before, its most often used to constrain a method return type with that lifetime.